# How to setup PayPal Pro to get payment through Debit/Credit card directly from website in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

The required solution for UK customer.

Magento 1  comes with Debit/Credit cart option with PayPal.

If we want the same thing then how can we achieve?

Please check this video for Magento 1 PayPal Pro Payment setup.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_Mhkqjob1I

The customer should have a direct option to enter credit/debit card detail while doing a checkout on Magento 2

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are detailed instructions for V2 at the Magento site here. A very swift Google lead me there. Hope this helps. Please mark answered if this helps obviously.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payments-pro.html

Comment: This solution is for the USA merchant

Comment: Good point, my apologies. It appears to be off the table for the moment stating not enough merchants offering PCI DSS compliance. That's terrible! I'll see what I can find out and try and offer some solution.

Comment: For now, it looks like you have to roll your own using Magento's Payment Provider Gateway via API... If you know SOAP or know someone that does, it doesn't seem too harsh. 

More on how here: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/payments-integrations/payment-gateway/payment-gateway-intro.html

This user looks to have done it, there's some useful pointers:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/NVP-SOAP-APIs/Stop-accepting-credit-card-payment-on-magento-2-website-with/m-p/1454809

Comment: Lol, just seen the ninja edit, I thought I'd missed it :)